# Why does Reaver get away with all he did in Fable 3?

Tags: fable-3

In Fable 3, Reaver is a pretty nasty person: the Hero personally sees him murder a worker in an intentionally slow and painful way for example, and he tries to get the Hero and Page killed in the Mansion.

So, how come the Hero will seemingly happily tolerate Reaver in their court for the year, once they're the monarch, with player having no option to bring him to the justice? And why nobody, for example Page, demands him to be punished (unless I remember wrong and someone does but it leads to nothing)?

Sure, Reaver runs the industry, but certainly a replacement could be found, especially after a good Hero doesn't let him follow his exploitative, murderous management style. Being useful doesn't prevent the player from choosing to have Logan executed, either.

Obviously, I'm looking for an in-universe explanation. I haven't read any of the Fable books, so perhaps they have some semi-plausible explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of universe, crappy writing and Reaver being a developer favourite that Lionhead wanted to keep for a sequel. But that's off topic and not the answer you want.

In universe, there are two reasons. First, he's wealthy and has a huge amount of political power. If the hero tried to have him executed and/or confiscate his industries, he has more than enough resources to rebel. Whether or not he would win is irrelevant- the result would be another civil war which would leave Albion too weak to defend itself.

Second, he's centuries old, hasn't aged and is a Hero. Notice how tall he is? He's capable of earning and spending experience and has probably been doing so since Fable 2 where he was already the Hero of Skill. One on one, he's more than a match for the player.

Comment: I go with the writing. I need look no further than the no win scenario. Which to talk about would spoil fable 3. But suffice to say... you need to be somewhat underhanded and quasi evil to save albion. Which to me, while more "real world realistic," just spits in the face of what the franchise was getting at.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to be evil. There is another way. Of course, that other way involves taking a LOT of jobs and probably becoming the landlord of most of Albion. Which I think is in keeping with the franchise. You can absolutely win while being Good. You just have to work harder.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's because he is a person of power. Both physical, political, and financial power. I really think the only way to take someone down from that high up is by killing the SOB... But I'm not sure that would work, considering the only game he's not in is Fable 1, suggesting something of an immortal nature... *cough* [Dorian Gray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Picture_of_Dorian_Gray) *cough*

However, in the storyline of the hero, (or you, the player), Reaver's *ahem* "habits" are a bit less important than saving all of mankind.

Answer (score -1):

Because for every good leader who never does anything wrog there is an evil bastard in the background taking care of matters, and yeah they are right you are a new hero at this point who has only been honing your craft for a few weeks you would be no match for the most skilled marksman to ever step on albion soil he could shoot you and all your generals in the head before you finished saying guards I order you to arrest that.....

Answer (score -2):

My theory for in game reason is it has something to do with the Shadow Court. Like a fog over everyone's mind when it comes to Reaver. No one ever seems to connect that he doesn't age. Maybe in the back of their minds they know they can't kill him.